# If element is there do A else do B in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement

**Final Edit:** *Just realized that I had set my implicit wait to 40 seconds so when `.isEmpty()` did its job it waited 40 seconds to go to the `else` statement. Thanks for all the help.*

The problem is that it gets to the if statement and just sits there and does nothing. The elementId does work as both pieces of code work if I remove the if test. One way I have tried:

```
if(!driver.findElement(By.id(elementId )).isDisplayed()){
   driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);

 }else{
   CenterOnClick.testFail(elementId , driver);     
   FailScreenShot.test(caseId, driver, targetNumberCell);

 }
```

another way: (***Finale edit: This one works for this problem.***)

```
 if(driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).isEmpty()){ //also used .size() > 0
   driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);

 }else{
   CenterOnClick.testFail(elementId , driver);     
   FailScreenShot.test(caseId, driver, targetNumberCell);

 }
```

I've also tried switching things around. The button I am trying to click is only available if you've not downloaded the file more than twice in a month. After that an error message takes it place. Weird thing is if I change the code to this:

```
 if(driver.findElement(By.id(elementId )).isDisplayed()){
   CenterOnClick.testFail(elementId , driver);     
   FailScreenShot.test(caseId, driver, targetNumberCell);

 }else{
   driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);


 }
```

it works, but only when the error message is showing. If the button is there it will still just sit there. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been at this for well over 16 hours.
Thanks.

Edit: I'm starting to think my problem has more to do with the website than my code.

Answer (score 1):

Please read WebElement documentation: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-

> - findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements,
>     use {@link #findElements(By)}    * and assert zero length response
>     instead.

In case of element not exist - you won't get "false" by `isDisplayed()` method, but `NoSuchElementException` from `find()`

so you should do something like: (`findElements`)

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).isEmpty()){
//do smth
}
```

Comment: `if(driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).isEmpty()){ //also used .size() > 0
   driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);` Was tried in the second step. Still does nothing. Now it did click the button but if the error message comes up it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).getLocation().getX();

if(x==0)
{
     driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);
}
else{
    CenterOnClick.testFail(elementId , driver);     
    FailScreenShot.test(caseId, driver, targetNumberCell);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing is happens.

Comment: could you please show the page where this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that I had set my implicit wait to 40 seconds so when .isEmpty() did its job it waited 40 seconds to go to the else statement. Thanks for all the help.

```
 if(driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).isEmpty()){ //also used .size() > 0
   driver.findElement(By.id(downloadId)).click();
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);

 }else{
   CenterOnClick.testFail(elementId , driver);     
   FailScreenShot.test(caseId, driver, targetNumberCell);

 }
```